# Android copyPixelsFromBuffer() to particular bitmap offset?

Tags: android, bitmap, java-native-interface, android-ndk, pixel

I am working on an Android application that deals with graphical operations in native code on a shared memory buffer. I have made functions to call my native code from Java using JNI, and my native code uses the JNI API to call Java from native code. Since copying large arrays of pixels has a significant effect on performance, I need to avoid it as much as possible.

The Android documentation for the Bitmap class talks of two ways for copying pixels onto the Bitmap internal buffer:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

setPixels(int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height)
Replace pixels in the bitmap with the colors in the array.

copyPixelsFromBuffer(Buffer src)
Copy the pixels from the buffer, beginning at the current position, overwriting the bitmap's pixels.

The problem with the API documentation is that it is very vague about what is happening behind the scenes when you use those functions. However, it is mentioned somewhere that copyPixelsFromBuffer() copies pixels directly without any internal color format conversion, as opposed to setPixels() which will in all case do that conversion even if the original pixels are in the target pixel format. Obviously, that is not something I want, since the pixels in my buffer are in the good format already.

Now, copyPixelsFromBuffer() looks very nice since it won't do that conversion, but the documentation does not talk of how to copy pixels from a buffer to a particular offset in the target bitmap. Oops, that is something very important, since I don't want to copy the entire buffer every time, but only a region on it. Yes, the documentation says that it is going to copy from the current position *in the source buffer* but nothing is said about the destination buffer. SetPixels() does the unnecessary conversion, but allows you to specify an offset in the destination buffer.

So, I am stuck between:

Copying only the region that I want at the cost of having pixel conversion

OR

Avoiding pixel conversion at the cost of copying the entire buffer every time

To get an idea, I may have a buffer representing a 1024x768 screen, with an invalid region that goes from (300,300) to (400,400).

If I copy only the region I need to update, I can copy and convert 100*100 pixels or copy without converting 1024*768 pixels. a 100x100 invalid region is small and only a particular case, most invalid regions would take a much larger portion of the buffer. Both methods have very negative effects on performance.

Does anybody have an idea on how I could copy pixels from my buffer to a particular offset on the target buffer, without forced pixel conversion? That would be the best of both worlds, and I don't see why it does not appear to be available.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

My guess is maybe the function doesn't take a destination offset because it just automatically uses the source offset for both source and destination. You should try it out.

-n

Comment: I thought the same, but the actual implementation of copyPixelsFromBuffer suggests otherwise: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java;h=7ca374164096b55ce609d79c1914efc7a5575722;hb=master